# Liferay 6. Redirect users to their private page after login

Tags: liferay

How to redirect users to their private page after login? Now it goes to /web/guest/home
I want to make this dynamic like `/web/<user>/home`. is there an easy way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "easy" way. You will need to write a login hook, that handles the redirect:

This is covered in several places of the Liferay Wiki:

- http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-action
- http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing+the+default+page+after+login

It also pops up in the Liferay forum quite frequently:

- http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/267390#_19_message_267390
- http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1814620#_19_message_1814620
- http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6477579

Comment: Im not a java programmer. I know C#.net any best way to start learning how create this hook?

Comment: The very first link contains an example